# Magento 2: Composer error when trying to update from 2.2.9 to 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I am trying to update magento to the latest version.

"composer update" quits with this message:

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 103.0.1
    - Installation request for magento/composer-root-update-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/composer-root-update-plugin[1.0.0].
    - Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.4].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires magento/framework 103.0.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.1].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 requires magento/framework 103.0.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 103.0.1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.1].
```

I have no idea what composer is trying to tell me.

Can anybody help me to decypher what is supposed to be wrong here or how to read these kind of messages in general?

Thank you

Comment: what upgrade guide did you follow?

Comment: the official: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: Please post you composer.json file